# JAVA : How to return value in generic function

Tags: java, generics

I am testing some small practicals with JAVA generics concept.

I try to return a List from a function that is generic but compile does not allow me to do so.

Check the code below :

```java
package com.test.generic.method;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Sample_3<T> {

    public <T> List<T> testReturn(T t) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T> ();
        list.add(t);
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        String s = "Gunjan";

        Sample_3 sample = new Sample_3<String>();
        List<String> list =(List<String>) sample.testReturn(sample);


        for(String ab : list){
            System.out.println(ab);
        }

    }
}
```

> It gives `ClassCastException`.

How can I return the list from the generic function ?
And why JAVA has added such compile time feature ?

Thanks,
Gunjan.

Comment: Is the purpose of this code to make Sample_2 a class that supports generics? or do you just want to use the generics as implemented with the java.util classes?

Comment: I just want to test it in the this class, how generic function works ans  how can it return a value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`The` purpose of the generics is to allow you freedom to specify. So you can do something like:

```
public List<T> testReturn(T t){
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        list.add(t); 
        return list; 
    }
```

which would then allow you to do e.g.

```
List<String> a = testReturn("A");
List<Integer> b = testReturn(1);
```

The issue with your code is that the intent of your method isn't really generic - the method is written to return a List<String>. The `<T>` in your code doesn't actually affect anything.

In response to your further question - 
You've written the following:

```
public class Sample_3 {
   public <T> List<T> testReturn(T t) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T> ();
    list.add(t);
    return list;
   }

   public static void main(String a[]) {
    String s = "Gunjan";
    // this is wrong - the Sample_3 class is not generic. It does not get a generic type parameter.
    Sample_3 sample = new Sample_3<String>();
    // this is also wrong. Since the method is generic the "T" you get is the same as the "T" that 
    // goes into the method. Here your String output type does not match the input type of the method,
    // which you've set here as a Sample_3 object
    List<String> list =(List<String>) sample.testReturn(sample);

}
```

Your generic parameter T sets the type that can vary. YOu can do it onthe method level, as above, or on the class level as well:

```
public class Sample_3<T> {
   public List<T> getList(){ ... }
}
```

e.g.

```
 List<Integer> l = new Sample_3<Integer>().getList();
 List<String> s = new Sample_3<String>().getList();
 List<Calendar> c = new Sample_3<Calendar>().getList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested the way you have specified here...its compiled but gives run time exception that ..ClassCastException : can not convert Sample_2 class to String...

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the signature:

```
public List<String> testReturn()
```

When you use `<T>` in a method declaration it tells the compiler you want to use a generic type in the method based on one of the parameters passed in.  Because you are not passing in any parameters with type `T`, the compiler cannot resolve `T` to a type.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a return type of a list of T, but returing a list of String. The quick fix is:

```
public List<String> testReturn(){
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  // add stuff to list;
  return list;
}
```

Really, the purpose of generics is to allow you to generify your class (i.e. Sample) so that you can create new instances of it, but specify what kind of objects it handles for each instance. Java checks these generics at compile time. Take List as an example - without generics, it doesn't care about what Objects I put into the list - which means I might put a Double into without getting a warning, and I don't know what kind of Object it contains when I call get(). We could write new classes or implementations of List that are limited to particular Objects - e.g. a StringList could only accept Strings - but that would be time-consuming and potentially difficult to maintain. Instead, Java generics allows us to restrict the input to / output from a particular List to a particular class (and any implementations of that class) - e.g. List only accepts and returns Strings.

e.g. to generify Sample:

```
public class Sample<T> {
  public List<T> makeEmptyList(){
    return new ArrayList<T>();
  }
}
```

You can also specify generics in static methods, but you have to pass the generic type in - either as an object or a class reference:

```
public static <T> List<T> makeAndAddToList(T t){
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
  list.add(t);
  return list;
}

public static <T> List<T> makeEmptyList(Class<T> clazz){
  return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

In your case, it's not clear whether your Sample classes should be restricting to handling Strings and List or whether it should be made generic.

For further info, check out the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: There's no need to pass in the `Class<T>` token unless it's needed for reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested the  code as you have mentioned. In my case I am passing a String object to the function makeAndAddToList(T t). So it will return a list of String  objects. Its fine, but it my case it gives ClassClassException..

Comment: Please see the question I have edited the code as you have explained in the answe

Answer (score 1):

I think the first question to ask is, why are you declaring the method to return `List<T>` when you are explicitly creating a `List<String>` within the method? That example isn't going to buy you anything by using generics. Is there some other scenario that you are trying to solve?

Just to give you a quick lesson, when Java compiles your classes, generics are removed from the bytecode. So, what may initially look like this in your editor:

```
public <T> List<T> testReturn(){
}
public List<String> testReturn2(){
}
```

Looks like this once compiled to bytecode:

```
public List testReturn(){
}
public List testReturn2(){
}
```

This is known as type erasure. The purpose of generics is to allow for compile-time parameter checking, thereby removing exceptions at runtime. An example of non-generic code that will produce a runtime error is the following:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Hello World");
list.add(Integer.valueOf(42));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String str = (String) list.get(i);
}
```

The String and the Integer placed in the List are incompatible types. Generics prohibit this kind of unsafe access/data entry (though it will always believe you when you cast something).

A generic 'display()' method would look like the following:

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Gunjan");
    list.add("Shah");

    new Sample_2().display(list);
}

public <T> void display(List<T> list) {
    for (T t : list) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

When using generics in a generic method, you must reference your generic values as though they are of an object type named, `T`

Comment: Thanks for the  reply.  Here you have given good explanation of the concept Type Erasure. But my question is that How can we return a value from a generic function ? I tested it .. it gives me classCastException.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting String objects in the List, then make the **List of type String**.

```
public List<String> testReturn(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Gunjan");
        list.add("Parth");
        list.add("Devang");
        return list; 
    }
```

Generics can be used with class, methods, variable, But its **most important use** it to make the **Collections more Type Safe**

`<T>` is called Type Parameters, if this is used in the method, then it means that, this is the Type to be used with in the method when it encounters a parameter with `type T`.